# Installing Elementary OS on an 2009 MacMini running El Capitan

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Zorin OS 15 on a 2009 MacMini running El Capitan so that it would dual boot. It crashed out at the last moment :(
The good news was that it didn't brick my MacMini
So does anyone have any experience of installing Elementary OS on this vintage of Macs?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have a macmini 2009 and the os is broken tried to repair it and fsck-ed it under single user mode but nothing worked. Bought a new mac air this could read the old hard drive in an external enclosure and could move the data from the old 500gb hard drive. Now I want to install elementary OS on the old mac mini. But how to do this when the mac OS is broke. I don't want to mess up the new mac. So i use a windows computer. Anyway I wil try to install elementary os and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently installed eOS 5.1 on 2009 iMac elCapitan and the install went fine.  Beautiful looking UI and I hope that I can get my bugs worked out so that I can stick with it.  I'm very new to Linux and first installed Linux Mint about a month ago so I'm just learning how to move around in Linux. I found eOS a week or so ago and have been using it since.  Here is the bugs I have so far so if you know how to fix it I'd love the help:

--Once the computer goes to suspend and turns the display off, coming back (mouse,spacebar, etc..) doesn't turn it back on.  The computer is awake since anticipating this if I instead enter the user password (with the screen black) and enter, I login and the display turns back on.  Mint didn't have this issue. This annoys my wife fiercely.

--The bluetooth "Magic Mouse" loses connection so often that it's better to use the usb mouse.  Mint didn't have this issue. This annoys my wife fiercely.

--I can't get the superdrive to play a dvd-- Tried different programs (VLC, etc..) I have Linux Mint installed on a similarly old macbook and plays dvd's fine.  I don't play many dvd's so it's not a real issue, but annoys me not-fiercely.